# How does this linklist flow?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

The structure of the node is as followed:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node *next;
};

// construct a new node 
    Node * cons( int x, Node* p) {
    return new Node{x, p};
}
```

Now if I were to type in my main body:

```
   Node *p;
   p = cons(3,nullptr);
   p = cons(2,p);
   p = cons(1,p);
   p = cons(4,p);
```

Is there a better value to start off with for my first node instead of nullptr?From what I understand this is 4 Nodes in order. Is that correct? Node value 3 is the first on the list. So this function would search my linklist in order as in goes to view node value 3, 2,1,4,then empty node.

```
//search linklist in order for value x
bool searchInOrder(int x, Node *p){
   while(p->next != nullptr){
   if(x == p->value)
      return true;
      p = p->next;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: All your main body does is leak memory.

Comment: The nodes are in inverse order of what you are thinking: p->4, p->next ->1, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't even parse a linked list.

Comment: @RSahu why is the linked list in reversed order?

Comment: @user3249265 because that is exactly how you built it. Each new node added refers their `next` to the current list-front, then *becomes* the list front with the final assignment back to `p`. If you want to build a linked list efficiently with forward-chaining you need to maintain some context of a tail pointer (of which there are multiple techniques). Otherwise the only alternative is to scan-to-end with each insertion, which quickly takes you down the road of [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) (pun intended).

Comment: thankyou,I think i get it, if you can post your answer with or without a small diagram i'd be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question:

> Is there a better value to start off with for my first node instead of `nullptr`?

Answer:

> That is the best way to create the first node of a linked list.

Question:

> From what I understand this is 4 Nodes in order. Is that correct? Node value 3 is the first on the list. So this function would search my linklist in order as in goes to view node value 3, 2,1,4,then empty node.

Answer:

> Yes there are 4 Nodes. However, the Node with value 3 is not the first Node in the list.

After

```
p = cons(3,nullptr);
```

The list is:

```
+---+        +-----+
+ p +  --->  |  3  |  ---> NULL
+---+        +-----+
```

After

```
p = cons(2,p);
```

The list is:

```
+---+        +-----+        +-----+
| p |  --->  |  2  |  --->  |  3  | ---> NULL
+---+        +-----+        +-----+
```

After

```
p = cons(4,p);
```

The list is:

```
+---+        +-----+        +-----+      +-----+        +-----+
| p |  --->  |  4  |  --->  |  1  |--->  |  2  |  --->  |  3  | ---> NULL
+---+        +-----+        +-----+      +-----+        +-----+
```